# str_split and \n counts as x characters

Tags: php, string, replace

I want to split a string so that every element of the array is only 112 characters long and that a newline counts as 28 characters.

Here is the code so far:

```
 $order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");

 $message3 = str_replace($order, '1234567890123456789012345678', 
 $_POST['message']);
 $messages2 = str_split($message3, 112);
 foreach ($messages2 as $message4) {
    $message4 =   str_replace('1234567890123456789012345678', '\n', $message4);
    $message[]=$message4;
 }
```

But this results most of the time in the 12345... splitted across 2 elements and they obviously do not get replaced.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Here's a question : How would you split a string which has 110 characters, then a line break (which counts as 28 characters), and then more characters ?

Comment: 110 charachters in array[0], then linebreak and more charachters in array[1].